# HTMLAgilityPack.HtmlNode does not contain a definition for remove

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to Remove empty nodes using below method. But I get the error on

```
containerNode.Remove();
```

saying "HTMLAgilityPack.HtmlNode does not contain a definition for remove....". What should I reference to use Remove method of HTMLAgilityPack other than 'using HtmlAgilityPack'.

```
  static void RemoveEmptyNodes(HtmlNode containerNode)
    {
        if (containerNode.Attributes.Count == 0 && (containerNode.InnerText == null || containerNode.InnerText == string.Empty))
        {
            containerNode.Remove();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = containerNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                RemoveEmptyNodes(containerNode.ChildNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

In one of my method I am using  below which is leaving out emtpy nodes like ,, etc

```
myNode.RemoveAll();
myNode.RemoveAllChildren()
```

How can i remove the empty nodes?

Comment: It was a version problem. Downloaded latest dll(1.4.6) and it solved the problem. I now have the remove method

Comment: Answer you question, and accept it if the issue is solved by yourself - don't leave a question unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a version problem. Downloaded latest dll(1.4.6) and it solved the problem. I now have the remove method